How to connect 2 Instruments in Controldesk dSpace via Python Script
im currenty trying to connect two or more Instruments in Control Desk from dSpace. For Example i Have a Numeric Input instrument and a Button. I want that the Button recieve the Numeric Input and i can conbine it with another numeric input. When the Button is pushed it should send it to the Labbox.
So the button Script acts like a Main Spcript and collect all the Inputs from other instruments.
Does anyone have an idea how to acomplish it?
I tried multiple Code attempts similar to this Example. https://www.dspace.com/de/gmb/home/medien/videos/tutorials/controldesk_ng.cfm#179_29737
Here is one Example. I would be very greateful if anyone could help.
# Code for Numeric Input: 
from win32com.client import Dispatch, DispatchWithEvents

class InstrumentEvents(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_los_button(self):
        if self.x_wert is None:
            if Instrument.Parent is not None and hasattr(Instrument.Parent, 'Children'):
                self.x_wert = Instrument.Parent.Children.Item('Los Button')

    def OnValueChanged(self, sender, oldState):
        self.get_los_button()
        if self.x_wert is None:
            return

        self.x_wert.Value = Dispatch(sender).Value

if Instrument.Parent is not None:
    InstrumentWithEvents = DispatchWithEvents(Instrument, InstrumentEvents)


# **Code for Button: **
from win32com.client import Dispatch, DispatchWithEvents

class InstrumentEvents(object):
    def __init__(self):


    def OnValueChanged(self, sender, oldState):

       x_wert = Dispatch(sender).Value

       Instrument.Value = x_wert

if Instrument.Parent is not None:
    InstrumentWithEvents = DispatchWithEvents(Instrument, InstrumentEvents)

